# Does $y^2 = x^6 - 3x^5 + 3x^4 + 10x^3 + 3x^2 - 3x + 1$ have any rational solutions?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, magma

Does $y^2 = x^6 - 3x^5 + 3x^4 + 10x^3 + 3x^2 - 3x + 1$ have any rational solutions?
I have some reasonable pre/post graduate Math skills but no access to Magma etc.
I suspect there are none other than the obvious 4 (0,1) (0,-1) (-1,2) (-1,-2), but I'd be interested to know for sure (if at all possible). I'm also mainly interested in $x>0$ (if that helps in anyway).

I'm also wondering if the fact that it is palindromic is of any consequence?

Comment: Run in **pari/gp** `hyperellratpoints(x^6-3*x^5+3*x^4+10*x^3+3*x^2-3*x+1,10^6)` - equation have at least four rational solutions.

Comment: Sorry, should have said ignoring the obvious $x=0$ or $x=-1$ and also intended $x>0$

Comment: So are the 4 @DmitryEzhov found the obvious ones also identified (0,1) (0,-1) (-1,2) (-1,-2)

Answer (score 2):

One most obvious, is $x=0 \implies y=\pm 1$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I've added comments to the question in that regard

Answer (score 2):

And another obvious solution: if we denote $p(x)$ the r.h.s., we have $p(-1)=4$; whence the solutions $\;(-1,-2)$ and $(-1, 2)$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I've added comments to the question in that regard